# Excel If statement in VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have huge issue with VBA. I want to write this statement:`=IF(C5<>0;(D5/C5);" ")`

at VBA code. But this:

```
Cells(y_2, 5) = "=IF(C" & y_2 & "<>0;(D" & y_2 & "/C" & y_2 & ");"" "")"
```

[image]

doesn't work and I have no idea what is wrong. y_2 is declared as Integer.

Help. Someone.

Comment: Put all code and formulas as text not pictures.

Comment: As you wish:
=If(C5<>0;(D5/C5);" ")
Cells(y_2, 5) = "=IF(C" & y_2 & "<>0;(D" & y_2 & "/C" & y_2 & ");"" "")"

Comment: Not in the comments [edit] you original post and put them there, so they can be formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ";" character to "," character

```
Cells(y_2, 5) = "=IF(C" & y_2 & "<>0,(D" & y_2 & "/C" & y_2 & "),"" "")"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your code from:

```
Cells(y_2,5) = "IF(C" & y_2 & "<>0;"(D" & y_2 & "/C" & y_2 & ");"" "")"
```

To this:

```
Sheets("YourSheetName").Cells(y_2,5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]<>0;RC[-1]/RC[-2];"""")"
'remember to change the name of your sheet above
```

Comment: Try adding the ActiveSheet or your Sheets("YourSheetNameHere") before the Cells, so for example Sheets("Sheet1").cells(y_2,5).Formular1C1

Comment: Nope, the same :/ but without equal sign it works `Cells(y_2, 5) = "IF(C" & y_2 & "<>0;(D" & y_2 & "/C" & y_2 & ");"" "")"`

Comment: Well that's a bit odd, have you defined a With Block? how does the macro know which sheet Cells refers to? Anyways... I guess as long as you got it working then it's fine... Please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you at all? Thanks.